# Identifying the kernel of induced homorphism with the kernel of group action of G on the left cosets of H

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, semidirect-product

Here is the exercise from Aluffi's Algebra.

Let $G=N \rtimes_\theta H$ be a semidirect product, and let $K$ be the subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $\ker(\theta) \subseteq H$.
Prove that $K$ is the kernel of the action of $G$ on the set $G/H$ of left cosets of $H$.

Let $(n, h)$ be an element of the kernel of the action of G.

Then, for any $(n', h')$, we should have $(n, h)•(n', h')=(n', h'')$ (Since we consider the kernel of the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$, It doesn't need to consider how the choosen element behaves on $H$ is.)

and then it is that actually $(n, h)•(n', h')=(nhn'{h}^{-1}, h'')=(n', h'')$ for any $(n', h')$.

Then $n$ should be $1_N$ (consider $H$ of the left cosets of $H$).
So here we can see $h$ conjugates every  $n$ in $N$ in the following way $hn{h}^{-1}=n$, which is precisely the element of $\ker(\theta)$.

And the converse implication is straightforward.

Is this right? Can you give me more direct proof? I feel like I did too much calculation which is not necessarily needed.

Any comment will be appreciated. Tha  nk you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your attempt correctly, you seem to assume that $\theta_h$ is $hn'h^{-1}$. This isn't necessarily the case. Keep in mind that $N$ and $H$ are arbitrary groups and the latter expression might not even make sense.

To prove the direction you're interested in, first note that any element of $G/H$ can be represented by $(x, 1)H$ for some $x \in N$. This simplifies the following computation a bit.

Next, let $(n, h)$ be an element of the kernel of the action of $G$ on $G/H$. For all $x \in N$, we have
$$(n, h)(x, 1)H = (x, 1)H.$$

Thus,
$$(x^{-1}, 1)(n \theta_h(x), h) \in H.$$

It follows that $x^{-1}n\theta_h(x) = 1$, and therefore $\theta_h(x) = n^{-1}x$. Since $\theta_h$ is an automorphism of $N$, this forces $n = 1$ and $\theta_h = 1$ as desired.

Comment: You mean $x \in N$. Secondly, the homomorphism $\theta$ can be realized as a conjugation because we can view $G$ as $G=NH$ with $N \cap H = \left\{e_G\right\}$.

Comment: You're right regarding $x \in N$. Fixed now. Thanks. As for your second note, it's true that $\theta$ can be realized as conjugation (proposition 5.10). Notation-wise, this is true when $N$ and $H$ are viewed as subgroups of $G$. It gets confusing when conjugation is done to components of pairs of elements of $N \rtimes_\theta H$. It's a technicality, and I believe it can be resolved.